# How to get IP/Hostname of All Hosts in a Molecule / TestInfra test?

Tags: android, molecule

i have a simple role, which just gets the ip/hostnames of all hosts in the play, and updates the /etc/hosts file.

```
- name: Add the inventory into /etc/hosts
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/hosts
    regexp: '.*{{ item }}$'
    line: "{{ hostvars[item]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }} {{item}}"
    state: present
  when: hostvars[item]['ansible_facts']['default_ipv4'] is defined
  with_items:
    - "{{ groups['all'] }}"
  become: true
```

I want to also have a test for this, for molecule.  I am somewhat familiar with molecule/testinfra, and know how to make tests loop through, and how to check the content of files etc.  I do not know how to get the ip/hostnames from this test, and then use those to verify they exist in the /etc/hosts file.

```
v = host.ansible.get_variables()
```

I imagine that would contain the information I need, but I see no way to print that information out from molecule/testinfra so i can actually see it.  If I was able to actually see the ip's, i know i could use them like in the below:

```
def test_conf_custom(host):
    conf = host.file(
        '/etc/hosts'
        ).content
    expected = [
        b'hostname',
        b'443',

    ]
    for line in expected:
        assert line in conf
```

Comment: See https://github.com/William-Yeh/docker-ansible/issues/4#issuecomment-149084120 which says this won't work i.e. you can't edit the container's /etc/hosts like this.